# TinyMCE with active admin doesnt load in production with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce, activeadmin

I have everything working in development, but I just pushed to production and the tinyMCE toolbar isn't loading. I am getting the following error.

> GET https://www.luminoto.com/javascripts/active_admin_custom.js 404 (Not Found)

I am using the rails gem
https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails

I feel like it isn't reading the correct path in  the active admin initializer `config.register_javascript 'active_admin_custom.js`

Here is my custom js file

```
//= require active_admin/base
//= require tinymce

$(document).ready(function() {
  tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    editor_selector : "tinymce",
    fontsize_formats: "14pt 16pt 18pt 20pt 24pt 30pt 36pt",
    toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link image | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist | numlist",
    browser_spellcheck : true,
    plugins: "link,wordcount,advlist",
    link_title: false,
    autosave_interval: "20s",
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you precompiled the assets? `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html